# python matplotlib bar chart adding bar titles

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib with python 2.7

I need to create a simple pyplot bar chart, and for every bar, I need to add, on top of it, the y value of it.

I am creating a bar chart with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

barlist = plt.bar([0,1,2,3], [100,200,300,400], width=5)

barlist[0].set_color('r')
barlist[0].title("what?!")
```

the changing of color works, but for the title i get the following error: 
AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no attribute 'title'

i found some [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931224/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart) about similar question but they are not using the same way of creating a bar chart, and their solution did not work for me.

any ideas for a simple solution for adding the values of the bars as titles above them?

thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The `matplotlib.pyplot.bar` documentation can be found [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar). There is an example form the documentation which can be found [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) which illustrates how to plot a bar chart with labels above the bars. It can be modified slightly to use the sample data in your question:

```
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [0,1,2,3]
freq = [100,200,300,400]
width = 0.8 # width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x, freq, width, color='r')

ax.set_ylim(0,450)
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
ax.set_title('Insert Title Here')
ax.set_xticks(np.add(x,(width/2))) # set the position of the x ticks
ax.set_xticklabels(('X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5'))

def autolabel(rects):
    # attach some text labels
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)

plt.show()
```

This produces the following graph:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As of matplotlib 3.4.0, you can use the built-in [**`plt.bar_label`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html) helper method to [auto-label the bars](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_label_demo.html).

Supply `containers[0]` from the current axes:

```py
plt.bar([0,1,2,3], [100,200,300,400])
ax = plt.gca()
plt.bar_label(ax.containers[0])
```

Or if you have grouped bars, iterate `containers`:

```py
for container in ax.containers:
    plt.bar_label(container)
```

[image: plt.bar with plt.bar_label]